# Making a pandas dataframe out of HTML

Tags: python, html, pandas

I am trying to convert word documents `.docx` to a dataframe. These docx files are first converted to HTML using the following:

```
#fill path in function 
path = os.chdir('C:jan_2021')
filename = "newsupdatedocx"
regex = '\xc2\xb7'

with open(filename, "rb") as docx_file:
    result = mammoth.convert_to_html(docx_file)
    text = result.value # The raw text
    text2=re.sub(u'[|•●]', " ", text, count= 0) 
    with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as text_file:
        text_file.write(text2)
```

This provides the following HTML output:

```
print(prettify)
<html>
 <body>
  <p>
   Newsupdate of date 01-01-2021
  </p>
  <h1>
   Header - worldwide news - category nr 1.
  </h1>
  <h2>
   Header - title of article nr. 1
  </h2>
  <p>
   Source: economist, google, NYTimes
  </p>
  <ul>
   <li>
    First bullet point related to article 1
   </li>
   <li>
    Second bullet point
   </li>
 </p>
 </body>
```

As you can see, converting the document to HTML provides a structure to it that can be analyzed accordingly. Now I would like to convert this to a dataframe. I want to make a list out of all elements in order to iterate over the list and to check if it is a `<h1>` element or `<h2>` elements in an item of a list. Ultimately, I want to have a dataframe with columns: date , type of news , article title , source before list items and lastly, items (bullet points).

The first step is to convert all elements to a list, so is there a certain function that converts this HTML to a list?

Comment: You can use beautifulsoup to convert html table to pandas dataframe.

Comment: The problem is, it does not find any table unfortunately. The word file is not in a table format, it has a simple top-down structure without any columns.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, using the following code:

```
tags = soup.find_all(['p', 'h1', 'h2', 'li'])
```